# QWebView Wait for load

Tags: c++, qt, loading, qwebview

```
bool MainWindow::waitForLoad(QWebView& view)
{
    QEventLoop loopLoad;
    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), &loopLoad, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &loopLoad, SLOT(quit()));
    timer.start(timeout);
    loopLoad.exec();
    if(!timer.isActive())
    {
        timer.stop();
        view.stop();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Say me, is that a correct code? App sometimes freezes after line

```
loopLoad.exec();
```

And always returns true even here has happened some problem (timeout, errors when loading, ect -- always true).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`start(timeout);` starts the timer with a timeout interval of msec milliseconds. So after calling it the  timer is running and `timer.isActive()` always returns true and the if block does not get executed.

You should stop the timer when loadFinished is emitted :

```
QObject::connect(&view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), &timer, SLOT(stop()));
```

If the timer is active then the event loop is stopped by the timer so you should return false because a timeout has been occurred. You should replace `if(!timer.isActive())` with `if(timer.isActive())`.

The correct code is :

```
bool MainWindow::waitForLoad(QWebView& view)
{
    QEventLoop loopLoad;
    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), &loopLoad, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(&view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), &timer, SLOT(stop()));
    QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &loopLoad, SLOT(quit()));
    timer.start(timeout);
    loopLoad.exec();
    if(timer.isActive())
    {
        timer.stop();
        view.stop();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Was it the reason of crashes? Or may it be the reason? (I used logs and all bugs were happening here)

Comment: I doubt it's the reason of crash. May be some other place in your code which calls this function is causing it.

Comment: I'm testing it, ~1h with no bugs. Before fixing it happened each ~2-5h. Also each line of my code is going to log. Bug happened on loopLoad.exec(); line only, because I think issue is only here

Comment: It still crashes. "QIODevice::write: device not open" -- I see this in app's output. When app crashes outputs "QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2". And app crashes on 'loopLoad.exec();' line as I see in logs. I will add additional info later