# Returning data with a slot

Tags: c++, qt

I want a function to return some data but it's containing the function connect(). This function downloads informations from the internet and using connect() allows me to wait for the end of the download before doing the rest of my function. As I'm using a slot, I can't return the data. Do you have an idea how I'm supposed to proceed?

Here is my code

```
QVariantList TheMovieDB::search(const Movie &movie)
{
    api_mode="search/movie";
    api_queries="&fr&query=" + title;
    api_query=api_url+api_mode+api_key+api_queries;
    view->load(QUrl(api_query));
    QObject::connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(resultSearch(bool))); 

    //here I want to return the datas in a QVariantList    

}

void TheMovieDB::resultSearch(bool)
{
   QString plainText = view->page()->currentFrame()->toPlainText();
   QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(plainText.toUtf8());
   QJsonObject jsonObj = document.object();
   QJsonArray obj = jsonObj["results"].toArray();

   for(int i = 0; i < obj.count(); i++){ //I want to return these informations
       qDebug() << obj[i].toObject()["title"].toString();
       qDebug() << obj[i].toObject()["id"].toInt();
       qDebug() << obj[i].toObject()["release_date"].toString();
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't (practically) get the result in the method you want. Redesign! Rename `search` to `startSearch` or something, and see where that takes you...

Comment: You probably want `QNetworkAccessManager` unless you want to display raw JSON text to your users.

Comment: Actually, I want to call this method from another class. So I would like to send a QVariantList or a QJsonArray. What's the difference between QNetworkAccessManager and QWebView?

Comment: `QWebView` is a GUI widget, for displaying webpages on the screen. `QNetworkAccessManager` is a non-GUI class, for downloading files over HTTP to be processed in some other way.

Comment: Ok but I'm having a look at a tutorial on how to get the source of an internet page. Even with QNetworkAccessManager, I have to use the function connect(). So I'm not sure it'll solve my problem.

Comment: Using an other event loop is the best choice for you. Have a look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218444/qwebview-wait-for-load

Comment: Oh ok. I have to use connect again just to send a parameter to my main function. That's pretty strange but ok, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't return the search() method. I think instead, call the SLOT when loadFinished(), add all the variants in a global QVariantList variable. You can always create a function returning your list.

Pseudo code:

```
int main()
{
    view = new QWebView(this);
    connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(), triggered()), this, SLOT(makeList()));
}

void search(const Movie &movie)
{
     //load to view
}

void makeList()
{
     myList.clear();
     //some stuff
     foreach(stuff)
          myList.append(stuff);
}

QVariantList getList(const Movie &movie)
{
     search(movie);
     return myList;
}
```

Now you can call getList() function from outside, provided it's a public function.

I'm not the best coder, but I would do it this way.

Edit: IMHO, every function should do only one thing.

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work. myList is always empty when I'm calling it. I think return(myList) doesn't wait for the end of makeList before returning myList.

Comment: Have you tried it with simpler code? Maybe you're returning the data correctly, but you're not getting it or adding it to the list correctly in the first place.

Comment: I've tried it checking everywhere the myList length with qDebug(). In makeList, it's 54, after search(Movie), it's 0. myList.clear() works but "return myList" is faster than "some stuff".

Comment: @user3499602 You can use for example a `listReady` signal to notify some object when the list is ready. Emit this signal at the end of the `makeList` method. Connect this signal to a slot and in this slot call the `getList` method. You'll need to move the call for the `search` method somewhere else. This way you will avoid getting the list before it's been updated.

Comment: @thuga That's a good approach. I tried, but couldn't come up with a better solution.

Comment: I don't understand. If I call getList in a slot, I can't return the datas. I need to call getList from another class, so it needs to be accessible from outside.

Comment: @Avatar36 You do know that you can connect the `listReady` signal to a slot in some other class, right? Then from a slot in this other class you can call `getList` to get the data. It's the same concept that is used for example in the `QTcpSocket` class. It emits a [`readyRead`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal when there is new data available. You connect a slot to this signal and use that slot to get the data from `QTcpSocket`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local event loop to wait until it's loaded :

It can be like :

```
QVariantList TheMovieDB::search(const Movie &movie)
{
    api_mode="search/movie";
    api_queries="&fr&query=" + title;
    api_query=api_url+api_mode+api_key+api_queries;
    view->load(QUrl(api_query));

    QEventLoop loopLoad;
    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), &loopLoad, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), &timer, SLOT(stop()));
    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &loopLoad, SLOT(quit()));
    timer.start(timeout);
    loopLoad.exec();
    if(timer.isActive())
    {
        timer.stop();
        view.stop();
        return QVariantList();
    }
    else
    {
        return resultSearch(true);
    }
}
```

Here you stop the timer and quit the event loop when `loadFinished` is emitted.

If the timer timeout is done and `loadFinished` is not emitted yet, the local event loop is quited. Now we check and if the timer is active, it shows that timeout is occurred and load has not finished, so we return an empty list. Otherwise we call `resultSearch` and return it. I assumed that you return the `QVariantList` in `resultSearch`;

Comment: I would not recommend this approach for reasons mentioned [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_wait_synchronously_for_a_Signal_in_Qt).

Comment: @thuga Definitely the asynchronous approach is better. I just mentioned this approach because the OP wants it here.

Comment: He might think he wants it, but he doesn't :).